# Segfault: and the disassembly is different between objdump and gdb

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb, objdump

[Deep breath.]
We have an application that pops up a window using WxMotif 2.6.3 (the GUI library was not - and is not - my choice).
It runs fine on the 32-bit ix86 systems. I had the task of converting it to a 64-bit application. It always seg-faults.
I'm on RHEL 6, so I compiled using gcc 4.4.7. After much gnashing of teeth, the problem seems apparent: in wxFrame::DoCreate, m_mainWidget is set (correctly); in wxFrame::GetMainWidget, it is returned as a null pointer. The null pointer results in the crash.
Using gdb, the instruction that sets m_mainWidget is

```
mov    %rax,0x1e0(%rdx) # $rdx = 0x68b2f0
```

whereas the code that gets m_mainWidget is

```
mov    0x1f0(%rax),%rax # $rax = 0x68b2f0
```

In gdb, I can examine the memory and see that the pointer at 0x68b4d0 is correct. Why is the offset incorrect?

To confuse things even more, when I use objdump to disassemble libwx_motifd_core-2.6.so.0.3.1, the "get" assembly is

```
  mov    0x1e0(%rax),%rax
```

In objdump, both the get and the set use 0x1e0 as the offset. What is going on?

I've uploaded some relevant info here:
[GitHub](https://github.com/hendrixjl/wxmotif_problem)

I've included a small program that replicates the problem on my system.

Investigating further, I see in the disassembly of wxFrame::DoCreate, that further uses of m_mainWidget retrieve the value using 0x1e0 as the offset (The disassembly is on a compile where I used -O0, so the code has to go back to the memory each time).
"Just for Fun," I added a new member variable to wxFrame - m_myMainWidget - and set it right after m_mainWidget was set. I then had wxFrame::GetMainWidget() return the local value (m_myMainWidget). Wouldn't you know it: The crash still occurs and GetMainWidget contains the same +16 offset when I disassemble from within gdb. (The offset is *not* there where I use objdump to disassemble.)

Comment: Could this be a difference in compiler optimization levels?

Comment: same behavior whether I use -O2 or -O0.

Comment: Could it be a (dynamic) linking problem?

Comment: not knowing wxMotif, is their code between the get and the set?

Comment: Somewhere, you have two translation units, or two modules, built with different compiler settings or different macro definitions. As a result, these two modules don't agree on the binary layout of the class. E.g. `class MyWidget { MyInt a; MyInt b; };` If `MyInt` is, say, typedef'ed as 32-bit integer sometimes and 64-bit other times, then the offset to `MyWidget::b` would be different.

Comment: Can you post some more context around the instruction? Are instructions around correct or are they corrupt too?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/tagged/wx/blob/master/include/wx/frame.h , there are macros that conditionally add or remove class members. That's scary. Be very very careful that you are defining these macros the same way in your application as they were defined when the library was built.

Comment: I posted stuff to https://github.com/hendrixjl/wxmotif_problem

Comment: @Igor: The "get" and "set" are both in the same translation unit. Sigh.

Comment: Maybe they are not in the same translation unit after all. The "get" is in an inline function in the declaration of the wxFrame class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Igor's comment, I have looked at the class layouts using the `-fdump-class-hierarchy` compiler option. It turns out that there is indeed a vtable layout mismatch, due to this conditional block in `include/wx/app.h`:

```
#ifdef __WXDEBUG__
    virtual void OnAssert(const wxChar *file,
                          int line,
                          const wxChar *cond,
                          const wxChar *msg);
#endif // __WXDEBUG__
```

You need to make sure you compile your code with the same `__WXDEBUG__` setting.

Comment: I think the answer is here somewhere. I would have said that both calls were in the same translation unit, but I just moved the function definition for wxFrame::GetWidget into the ./src/motif/frame.cpp file and recompiled, and the problem seems to be fixed.  I'm not sure how *any* of the macros (like __WXDEBUG__) could have been different from one translation unit to the next, since I compiled the all using ./configure; make; make install without changing it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The macro was not defined while compiling your code, not the library. Your `MainApp` inherits from `wxAppConsole`, but without `WXDEBUG` its vtable is missing the entry for `OnAssert` and thus has different layout than what the library expects (because that was compiled with `WXDEBUG`).

Comment: [Hitting myself in the head] How stupid of me! Thanks a bunch. You've given me a new tool to use (-fdump-class-hierarch).